# Displaying an Image in a WebBrowser Control without accessing external Files

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, webbrowser-control

I am using the WebBrowser Control in C# in [an application](http://swiki.codeplex.com/) to display HTML. All the data comes from a database, so I am generating a full page with Inline-CSS in Memory and sending it to the browser.

But now I want to support images, which seems to be a problem because I do not want to store the images on Hard drive, not even in a Temp Directory. I am aware of the [data: URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), but that seems to be too limited.

I wonder: Can I somehow use JavaScript to dynamically generate an image, given a stream of bytes, essentially mirroring the data: Scheme using JavaScript? Or is there some other way to display images, i.e. using GDI+?

I can make some assumptions about the images if required, i.e. I can force the user to specify width and height if required, but I cannot really enforce the position, it's HTML after all. I can also force all images being in a specific format, basically anything that could help solving this.

**Edit:** Could I maybe abuse something like [VML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VML) to display Bitmap data? I can't use Canvas or SVG as it seems (both unsupported in IE and therefore in MSHTML?)

**Edit 2:** VML would work, but the processor load is insane. So I'll either implement a Webserver to serve files (like cassini) or try the [Silverlight approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223166/) in my other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to add an extra layer of complexity to your application then you can embed a simple web server that can be used to serve the images. 
Using the [System.Net.HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) you can setup your application to serve the images as requested. This should work, but it seems terribly hackish...

Comment: hmmm... That is actually not that much of a hack. The only possible issue is a Firewall complaining about my Application listening on a port, but it could connect on 127.0.0.1:unused_port and serve the images. Thinking about it, that is a neat solution.

Answer (score 2):

The img-tag supports inline data in its source attribute. So you can take your image data, base64-encode it, and store it inside the src attribute.

[Look here for an example.](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html) og you can google for [html embed image](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+embed+image) for more examples.

Comment: The problem with the data: scheme is that it's not supported by older Internet Explorer Versions and that it's limited to 32k in newer ones :-(