# Completely embedding a Silverlight Application in an HTML Page?

Tags: .net, silverlight

I am still trying to solve the issue of displaying an image on a website without having the image external. As the data: scheme does not work on older browsers or big images, I'm currently experimenting with Silverlight.

I managed to solve the embedding by Base64 Encoding the Image and passing it in using the InitParams, but actually I just moved my problem away: Instead of an external Image, I now have an external XAP File...

Is there a way taking the XAP File and somehow embedding it in the HTML? Or alternatively, can I use the JavaScript-based Silverlight 1.1 in this situation? It's literally just displaying an image that has been passed in as a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to do, it sounds like you might want to look at Sam Ruby's [SVG with XAML fallback](http://intertwingly.net/blog/2007/05/04/Inline-SVG-in-MSIE), which displays SVG in browsers which support it, and renders via Silverlight in IE.

You can inline XAML like this (source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189016(VS.95).aspx)):

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Display Date</title>
      <!-- Define Loaded event handler for TextBlock. -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function setDate(sender, eventArgs)
        {
          sender.text = Date();
        }
      </script>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="Teal">

    <!-- Define XAML content. -->
    <script type="text/xaml" id="xamlContent"><?xml version="1.0"?>
      <Canvas
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"
        Background="Wheat">
        <TextBlock
          Canvas.Left="20"
          FontSize="24"
          Loaded="setDate" />
      </Canvas>
    </script>

    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
      <object type="application/x-silverlight" width="100%" height="100%" id="slc">
        <param name="source" value="#xamlContent"/>
        <param name="onload" value="onLoaded" />
        <param name="iswindowless" value="true" />
      </object>
      <iframe style='visibility:hidden;height:0;width:0;border:0px'></iframe>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Note that Firefox 2 had a bug ([bugzilla 356095](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=356095)) which [prevented using this with XHTML DOCTYPE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightdeveloper/thread/fa56fcd5-1745-4412-999c-123bf73efd62). I believe this may be fixed.