# Cannot serve out file in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, file, arrays

I have a byte[] that contains all the data that represents an image. How do I serve it out as an actual Image in a browser ? The following code returns just a list of bytes:-

```
List<HubAsset> hubAsset = _core.GetHubAssets(query);
            byte[] file = Convert.FromBase64String(hubAsset[0].Data);                               
            return file;
```

Comment: You're trying to send this as a response from a WCF service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Streaming byte\[\] to Image in ASP.NET C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346519/streaming-byte-to-image-in-asp-net-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been on SO already:

[Streaming byte[] to Image in ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346519)