# Uploading Images - Security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-3

## Setup:

I am writing the Admin utility for an eLearning Package.  Using this utility, the Tutors can write their courses, add/upload images, etc.

My problem is regarding security vulnerabilities when uploading files, specifically, image files.

The following code is my controller code for the POST that uploads a new image file:

```
[HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult StepImage(int CourseId, int StepOrder, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            service.CourseId = CourseId;
            service.StepOrder = StepOrder;
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                if ((fileExtension == ".jpg") || (fileExtension == ".gif") || (fileExtension == ".png"))
                {
                    service.StoreImageFileName(fileName);
                    var path = Server.MapPath("~/[path to where images are uploaded]/" + service.CourseId + "/");
                    if(!Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    }
                    file.SaveAs(path + fileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Refactor notice : Validation for invalid file extension
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Refactor notice : Validation for no file chosen
            }

            return RedirectToAction(MVC.Admin.StepEditor.Actions.Edit(CourseId, StepOrder));
        }
```

You can see from the above code that I check for the file extension and only allow .jpg, .gif and .png.

## Questions

1. I tried storing the files under the App_Data folder, but this resulted in a 403 forbidden response when the Views try to display the images.
2. So I put them in ~/Images/...

Is there a security risk with this?  Can someone upload an .exe file with a .jpg extension and get it to execute baddie code?

It has to be said that the risk is low, as only Tutors will have permissions to use the page that uploads the file, but you just need one disgruntled tutor... Or they give their login details to a student... or whatever.

1. Any other security risks in that code?

### PS:

The basics are taken from Scott Hanselman's and Phil Haack's blog posts on the subject of uploading files using ASP.NET MVC 2 +:

[Phil Haack post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx)

[Scott Hanselman post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx)

Comment: I'd add code that checks if the file starts with the correct magic bytes for an image. So the user can't upload an `.exe` renamed to `.png`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get a 403 response when you place the images in the App_Data folder because IIS prevents any browser from directly accessing files in App_Data.

Placing them in ~/Images/ works but depending on the security on that folder this could mean that anyone can list the contents of ~/Images/ and/or view the images. By default, IIS forbids listing the contents of any folder but viewing the images by anyone is allowed. So, if someones knows the filename of the images, they can view them.

A solution is to use [URL based authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx). Only the tutors (or whoever needs to) will be able to see the images then.

If you want complete control over who sees what on what pages, you could still place the images in the App_Data folder and then stream them to who- or whatever needs them [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346519/streaming-byte-to-image-in-asp-net-c).

About uploading an .exe as a jpg, this is certainly possible. It will even work for any type of file.

However, you save the file to the disk and don't do anything yourself with it. That makes the risk very small that the .exe-as-jpg is executed on your server. Unless someones finds an exploit in .net code that forces .net to execute the jpg, this is very unlikely.

You also show the jpg to the user in your views. That carries once again the security risk that possibly the user's browser has an exploit that forces it to execute the .exe-as-jpg on the user's computer. However, I think that is still very unlikely to happen (but not impossible. It has been done before e.g. [see this](http://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/ms04-028.shtml)).

To prevent this, you would need code on your server side that checks every image to see if it really is an image. However, these (possibly non-existent) security risks are very small and even exploiting this risks would require someone who knows quite a lot of computers and programming. Personally, I wouldn't worry about this.

Absolute security is impossible (Well, short of never turning your computer on. If it doesn't do anything, nothing can go wrong after all). It all depends how much security you want and how much time & money you can invest.

Comment: I was aware of where the 403 response comes from, but there is other detail of value in your response.  So you get the biscuit.