# 403 Forbidden: Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-403

I'm writing a web application that have to download user profile pictures from another web sites and store those pictures in web server. I have the downloading function working, but when I'm trying to show that picture in web browser picture is not showing up, I found that for the file request from the browser my server is giving

```
403 Forbidden
```

Is this a permission issue?
How can I serve these pictures from my application?

Comment: Which folder you are storing the file? App_Data?

Comment: Yes I created App_Data Folder in the same level as Controllers, Views... and inside of that App_Data folder I have folder named pictures, this is where I store those pictures.

Comment: Are you reading the images from the App_Data folder?

Comment: thanks, I changed the folder name, now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS Don't allows to read files from the App_Data folder. An easy option store the profile pictures in some other folder.

[Uploading Images - Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978932/uploading-images-security)

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission issue. Ensure that the location that you are saving the file has at least read permission for everybody, so that it can be visible to those browsing the site.

Comment: By "everybody" do you mean the IIS Process? (IUSR)

Comment: Is there a place where I can change the permission to that folder

Comment: From Windows Explorer, right-click the folder, select the "Security" tab. The rest should be fairly obvious.