# How can I display a System.Drawing.Image on a webpage using an HTTP Handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

I have a control that returns a Dictionary of type string and System.Drawing.Image. I want to loop through the dictionary and output an ASP Image Control that displays the image contained in each Key Value Pair. I understand that this needs to be done via an HTTP handler, but am not sure quite how to go about it. Assuming that the image will need to be converted to a byte array and then returned as an output stream from the handler, how can the Image or byte array be passed as part of the context for the Handler?

Answer (score 0):

You may call the [Image.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx) method.

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
   image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return Content Type correctly and Stream, see
this  [link for refference](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/desaijm/httphandlersforimages11152005062705am/httphandlersforimages.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming that you are binding the dictionary object to a repeater and the HttpHandler name is imageHandler. So once the dictionary object is bound you are going to get something like

`<ItemTemplate> <asp:Image id="image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/imageHandler.ashx?k=" + Eval("key")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>`

in your httphandler read the query string which will give you the key then you can get system.drawing.image from the dictionary after which you can convert it into bytearray and proceed further.

You can further refactor your code so that you can get all the key values as a list or an enumerable and bind it then query the database in the httphandler.

`Response.Write(byte array) and response.contenttype= "give the correct content type"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the HttpHandler has no knowledge of the Dictionary Object so passing it the key is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Most examples available in the web passes an id to the ashx handler; the handler path along with the id is set as the source to the image control. In most cases for each request to the handler is going to access the DB and fetch the image, do the processing and render the image.

However in your case it seems you already have the dictionary of images (so you will need a way to pass that info to the handler). One way you can approach this is to cache the images as memory stream and at the ashx handler you can access cahced items and later clear the cache. This is already [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346519/streaming-byte-to-image-in-asp-net-c-sharp); but not the elegant solution.

You may also want to check [this blog post by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETFuturesGeneratingDynamicImagesWithHttpHandlersGetsEasier.aspx), where he talks of an extension to `<asp:image/>`