# Insert image into asp.net image tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image

I'm trying to display my picture out on the image tag at my webform in a web application which i used VS2012 to develop. I have already stored my image in a binary form in the sql server 2008. I attempted to display out the image through the c# codes. However, the image displayed out is the exact dimension size. I'm trying to store this particular selected into the image tag with a specific dimension. Here are my codes which i used to display out my image.

This code here is for me to select out the picture from the database. I managed to display the picture out by using this.

```
string strQuery = "select profilepic from LoginRegisterOthers where username=@username";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
            DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
            if (dt != null)
            {
                download(dt);
            }
```

This code then used to convert the image binary data into an image.

```
private void download(DataTable dt)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["profilepic"];
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Your code will allow you to download the image file. What do you wanna do?

Comment: I'm trying to store this particular selected into the image tag with a specific dimension

Answer (score 2):

<strike>What you do with the binary array needs to change (if I guessed correctly what you're trying to do)</strike>

This is an alternative technique of inserting binary contents into image tag.

Instead of just streaming the binary contents down to the browser, you could write it in the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag. The HTML you are aiming to have would look like [this example](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html) (note that the image contents is Base64-encoded):

```
<img   src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAAsLav///88PD9WqsYmApmZmZtZfYmdakyH5BAQUAP8ALAAAAABQAA8AAAPb
WLrc/jDKSVe4OOvNu/9gqARDSRBHegyGMahqO4R0bQcjIQ8E4BMCQc930JluyGRmdAAcdiigMLVr
ApTYWy5FKM1IQe+Mp+L4rphz+qIOBAUYeCY4p2tGrJZeH9y79mZsawFoaIRxF3JyiYxuHiMGb5KT
kpFvZj4ZbYeCiXaOiKBwnxh4fnt9e3ktgZyHhrChinONs3cFAShFF2JhvCZlG5uchYNun5eedRxM
AF15XEFRXgZWWdciuM8GCmdSQ84lLQfY5R14wDB5Lyon4ubwS7jx9NcV9/j5+g4JADs=
" alt="British Blog Directory" width="80" height="15" />
```

Now, to accomplish this, you have probably several options. It all depends how you're rendering the `<img>` tag. If you're using a server-side control, then code like this may do (this sample snippet comes from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1346769/365968)):

```
byte[] picByteArray = user.Picture.ToArray(); 
string myPicString = Convert.ToBase64String(picByteArray); 
myPicture.Attributes["src"] = "data:image/gif;base64," + myPicString;
```

**ADDITION**:

One possible benefit of going that way is that, if design allows it or requires it, you could retrieve more than one image in a single database trip.

But as I also say in the comments, this method comes with the downside that images are processed synchronously, as your page is processed.

Comment: IF there are 100 images on a page, and we use this method, what will happen with the viewstate of page. Is it efficient method to do this? just confirming.

Comment: First of all you shouldnt show all 100 images at once. And if you have to do it, you only load a really small image for each one. Else your page will take forever to load completely

Comment: Not sure why you'd need ViewState for these objects. I see bigger problems with the sequential nature of doing 100 photos like that - both from browser's perspective, as well as web server page processing and db server round trips. You and your team are the best to decide - I guess I was only showing the technique.

Comment: @JikkuJosephJohn, I agree with your point that displaying a thumbnail version of the image is a better approach, than decreasing its size through HTML/styling.

Comment: @g-stoynev We should just upvote each other's answer seeing as the asker/questioner doesnt seem to be in any hurry to upvote/accept.

Comment: I dont really understand how do I use this method by getting the binary from SQL Server 2008. Still trying to learn

Comment: This method allows for assigning the binary content (read from the database) to the `<img>` tag `src` attribute as you're processing your "main" page (server-side events) - the page that contains the image. As opposed to rendering the `<img` tag and then having to call a stand-alone page dedicated to serving the image contents, which is what `<img src="MemberProfile.aspx?"...` does.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this url. One of the users has created a function that takes a System.Drawing.Image as input. You will probably have to write the binary data you download from your db into an object of type System.Drawing.Image before you call the function that is written in the page below

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a43fe625-a5cd-4438-895f-3ddeec6eb866/

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

- in  tag specify width and height of the image using CSS or html attributes. This causes that users will always download full size image but it will be displayed cropped
- in src of img tag put width and height like: `image.aspx?width=200&height=100`. Parse query string on server side and resize image on server.

Of course you can use mix of both.

Comment: I name my file as MemberProfile.aspx, so I put the img like this?
`<img alt="ProfilePic" src="MemberProfile.aspx?" width="200"height="100"/>`

Comment: That is first option. remove only ? from src. It is redundand if you not pass params

Comment: i did remove the ? only but the img still dont seem to be resizing.

Comment: There should be a space between `width="200"height="100"`

Comment: Even I put spacing in between it still dont resize on it own.

Comment: Do you have any errors or something on console? On JSfiddle i prepared you working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cacfc/

Comment: u getting that chrome image from website? I trying to retrieve image from database (SQL Server 2008) and put it into a img tag. I enter this code `<img alt="ProfilePic" src="MemberProfile.aspx?" width="200" height="100"/>` but it dont seem to resize or work? I got a question is it that the image must be taken from another code behind page instead of the using the same code behind page?

Comment: I get how it work now but still having a problem if the image column in database is empty it prompt error. Any idea how to set a default image for SQL Server 2008 using varbinary(MAX)?